# Jquery - Toolbar options or Toolbar plugin needed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, toolbar, jquery-tools

Can anyone suggest me a  `Jquery plugin` for `ToolBar` option in web application.Actually I tried and googled a lot and spent `two days`. But can't find reliable one.

If the suggested `toolbar` will be looks like the below pic means it would be the great one.Or else no problem. But suggest me some thing like ,

[image]

Home our stack users will help me.

Good answers are definitely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check this http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/ I think this will help you